# Does the only figure in a document get labeled as Figure 1?

Tags: technical-writing

If a document references only one figure, is it identified as "Figure 1" or no number assigned?

Comment: "Mechanical" style issues of this kind will depend on the place you want to publish. (Or submit for credit, etc.) Different editors etc. will have very different opinions. So no universal answer is possible. See what other authors have done when publishing in the same place. Find out if there is an official style guide.

Comment: Many thanks for your time and suggestion! I've been going through CMoS and not finding anything.

Answer (score 1):

I've written academic papers and I've been a peer reviewer.

I'd still label it figure 1, but I wouldn't reject your paper if you didn't.

You might call it by name; i.e. "The blueprint" or "The diagram" or "The flow chart".